# Evaluating functions related by Mobius inversion formula

Tags: arithmetic, number-theory

**Problem**

Consider two functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(k) = \sum_{d | k} g(d)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  So, the questions are:

- Let's say $f(k)$ is known for $k \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$. How to evaluate $g(k)$ for all $k \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$ within time $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$?
- Let's say $g(k)$ is known for $k \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$. How to evaluate $f(k)$ for all $k \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$ within time $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$?

**My approach**

I've noticed that $f(k) = \sum_{d | k} g(d)$ brings to mind Mobius inversion formula, that states the following:

$$ \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \quad f(k) = \sum_{d | k} g(d) \Rightarrow g(k) = \sum_{d | k} f\left( \frac{k}{d} \right) \mu(d), $$

where $\mu$ is the [Mobius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). I understand how to do the evaluation from the questions by pre-factorizing all the numbers $1, 2, \dots, n$, but then it doesn't work within desired $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ time. How can one do that faster than by factorization?

Comment: I think u may try to reduce the formula to something related to all prime no.s < n (every $d$ can be reduced to its prime factors). I think if u worked in that direction, u may reach a simpler formula